# How to reinsert data from one table onto itself using LINQ in code migration?

Tags: c#, linq, azure

I am following a tutorial on msft azure and it requires four fields to be auto generated. I need to add the four fields and then re insert all the data so that it can be auto generated using code migration?
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-use-existing-sql-database/

What would I put here?

```
protected override void Seed(CIMSMobileService.Models.CIMS_Mobile_Service context)
    {
        //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

        //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
        //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data. E.g.
        //
        //    context.People.AddOrUpdate(
        //      p => p.FullName,
        //      new Person { FullName = "Andrew Peters" },
        //      new Person { FullName = "Brice Lambson" },
        //      new Person { FullName = "Rowan Miller" }
        //    );
        //
    }
```

Comment: I think you have to add the fields to the table by an upgrade script (from migrations) and then update the records instead of reinserting them.

Comment: How do I update the records in data migration?

Comment: Use [`AddOrUpdate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn176991%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add this to your model and then add-migration and it will generate the commands to create those fields in your database - then you can seed your data. If you are adding them manually, you aren't using data-migrations and things will start to get out of sync when you want to add fields to your models in the future.

**EDIT**
As per the article mentioned below, they actually change the model and then use an initializer (ClearDatabaseSchemaIfModelChanges) that will DELETE all the table content and recreate the table with the new schema and see it with the data specified here

```
 public class ExistingInitializer : ClearDatabaseSchemaIfModelChanges
    {
        protected override void Seed(ExistingContext context)
        {
            List orders = new List
            {
                new Order { OrderId = 10, Item = "Guitars", Quantity = 2, Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()},
                new Order { OrderId = 20, Item = "Drums", Quantity = 10, Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()},
                new Order { OrderId = 30, Item = "Tambourines", Quantity = 20, Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() }
            };

            List customers = new List
            {
                new Customer { CustomerId = 1, Name = "John", Orders = new Collection {
                    orders[0]}, Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()},
                new Customer { CustomerId = 2, Name = "Paul", Orders = new Collection {
                    orders[1]}, Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()},
                new Customer { CustomerId = 3, Name = "Ringo", Orders = new Collection {
                    orders[2]}, Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()},
            };

            foreach (Customer c in customers)
            {
                context.Customers.Add(c);
            }

            base.Seed(context);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The data already exists. I just need to reinsert the data from table to itself so that the fields needed for azure can be generated. How do I this in LINQ?

Comment: email me adamt at microsoft - im still a big confused by what you need :) Ive looked at the article, they add the model and then use a ClearDatabaseSchemaIfModelChanges initializer which will DELETE all the mentioned tables and their data and recreate. Your data will be removed.

Comment: Send an email to you now.